# Getting SQL rows where >= 1 row have a certain value in another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've seen similarly worded questions, and I may be phrasing it wrong, but take the following example table:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 |

And say I know beforehand that I have `a` values `[1,2]`. How can I get all values of `b` that the `a` values share? In the above, the result would be `[8, 10]`. If I had `[1,3]` for `a`, then I would get `[10]`. If I had `[2]` for `a`, I would get `[6,8,9,10]`

I imagine it would start something like `SELECT b from tablename WHERE ...`

Comment: hint: GROUP BY and HAVING , or use row_number()

Comment: @MitchWheat I seem to have made some progress. I tried `SELECT b FROM tablename WHERE a in <values> GROUP BY b HAVING COUNT(*) == <size of values list>` - where `<values>` is the list of `a` values I am trying to determine the matching `b`s of . Anything look off here to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect`

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table test(a int, b int);

 insert into test values(1, 5);
 insert into test values(2, 6);
 insert into test values(3, 7);
 insert into test values(1, 8);
 insert into test values(2, 8);
 insert into test values(2, 9);
 insert into test values(1, 10);
 insert into test values(2, 10);
 insert into test values(3, 10);
```

Query1:
select b from test where a=1
intersect
select b from test where a=2

Output:

| b |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 10 |

Query2:

```
 select b from test where a=1
 intersect 
 select b from test where a=3
```

Output:

| b |
| --- |
| 10 |

Query3:

```
 select b from test where a=2
```

Output:

| b |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2a08552d6275f09ea21866d3ebf51934)*

Answer (score 0):

Create a CTE that returns the values of `a` that you want and filter the table for these values only.
Then `group by b` and in the `HAVING` clause filter the resultset so that only values of `b` that are associated to the values of `a` that you want are returned:

```
WITH cte(a) AS (VALUES (1), (2))
SELECT b
FROM tablename
WHERE a IN cte
GROUP BY b
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=04a827c6b6a72da4c89390eaa6728a0c).